# How to login to website with no Id's - VBA

Tags: vba

Would anyone know how to log in to this website in vba? I can't seem to find "Id's" for the username and password boxes. Let me know. THanks!

https://www.barchart.com/options/volume-leaders#/login

Answer (score 1):

One way...

```
Sub Login()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.barchart.com/options/volume-leaders#/login"
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim inputField As Object, inputFields As Object, btSubmit As Object, btn As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate URL
    IE.Visible = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set inputFields = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each inputField In inputFields
        If inputField.getattribute("name") = "email" Then
            inputField.Value = "Your login id"
        ElseIf inputField.getattribute("name") = "password" Then
            inputField.Value = "your password"
        End If
    Next inputField
    Set btSubmit = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each btn In btSubmit
        If btn.innertext = "Log In" Then
            btn.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btn
End Sub
```